# Do not get correct date/time

Tags: php

I have a PHP page in a server, located in the US.

The code in the page is

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

When I take this page, it gives a time, for example, 2010-10-26 10:20:07.

But when I refresh the page on the very next second, it gives the same date with a different time (a huge difference).

For example, 2010-10-26 08:25:58

What is the reason for that?

Comment: Check your timezone. `date_default_timezone_get()` and `date_default_timezone_set()`

Comment: it seems like server error. Contact your hosting service!

Comment: I agree with confiq. It seems there is something strange going on with the server.

Comment: Hi kijin
i have checked the timezone .it is 'America/Los_Angeles' and it doesn't changes only the time changes

Answer (score 2):

If you are on shared hosting someone might be changing the server locale or server timezone. Actually, two people might be changing it which causes it to jump back and forth each page refresh as one scripts sets it to one thing while another sets it to another thing.

Comment: do you know of any general cure-alls for this sort of behavior, or does it depend heavily on the host Linto is using?

Comment: But in that domain only this php page is there.No other page in the domain

Comment: If you mean domain as in the website domain (example.com) then I don't think it matters. The change is server wide. However, I'm not sure about certain "domains" (other use of the word). Have you tried kijins suggestion of `print date_default_timezone_get()`?